# Should I improve the answer or delete it and add another answer

Tags: discussion

This is the related question; screenshot below for users who don’t have enough reputation to see it:

[Is it possible to disable "Continue where you left off" in Chrome without opening it?](https://superuser.com/questions/987093/is-it-possible-to-disable-continue-where-you-left-off-in-chrome-without-openin/987179#987179)

I added an answer and a person commented on it saying that it is not a good one. The answer is quite a long solution and I found another easier and specific way.

Should I edit my answer adding both answers or delete it and answer only the easier more specific way?

My concern is that if I edit the answer that comment gets non related and nonsense.

[image]

Comment: It is entirely up to you if you want to delete the answer or not.  Take a hard look a the answer, if it does not answer the proposed question, you should  make sure you edit your answer so it does. **If the comment is or becomes obsolete then flag it.**

Comment: So flag the comment?

Comment: @Ramhound ok, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My concern is that if I edit the answer that comment gets non related and nonsense.

Comments can be deleted and often times become obsolete.  There's no need to worry about editing your answers because of this.

---

The way I approach situations like this is by following these criteria.  These aren't canon but simply the way I approach them:

- Does the edit to the answer significantly change the original answer?  If so, then I'll post another answer.
- Is the change to the answer due to changes in the original question?  If so, then I'll probably edit the original answer.
- Is there a value with two distinct answers, no matter how much one or the other *may* appear to be "better" solution?  If so, then I'll more than likely make two different answers
- Is the second "answer" and addendum or clarification of the first answer?  If so, then I'll just edit the original

Comment: Good rules of thumb.  I would clarify that, if you have two *distinct*, quality approaches to solving a problem, it's OK to post two answers to a question (without deleting either of them) — although you shouldn't make a habit of it (because it smells like rep farming).  I believe that this is consistent with your third bullet, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Scott that is the intention of the third bullet.  Updated for clarity.  Hopefully that helps.